# ORA-22835: Insufficient buffer size for converting CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW (actual: 81863, maximum: 2000)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, oracle21c

I am attempting to insert file byte array in database(Oracle) using C# application and Nhibernate version 5.4.6  and but I am getting the error below:

"ORA-22835: Insufficient buffer size for converting CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW (actual: 81863, maximum: 2000)".

But same is working fine with Nhibernate version 3.1.0.

Table column :
[image]

Column mapping is below :

```html
<property name="Image" type="BinaryBlob">
      <column name="IMAGE" not-null="false" sql-type="LONG RAW" />
</property>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `LONG RAW` for this? Oracle hasn't recommended using that data type for 30 years. Your program is presenting the data as a `BLOB` and Oracle can only cast the first 2000 bytes as RAW, by definition. Ideally your column should be a `BLOB` data type and avoid any implicit conversion.